# Mount container directory into volume directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mount, docker-volume

Basically I know about the mount syntax of docker and - unless I really did miss it - it does not allow to map a container directory into a specific directory inside a volume.

An example what I mean:
A container has an direcotry `/app` inside it and I have a named volume `user_data`. Now I would like to map the container directory `/app` into the volume `user_data` but at the path `/example` inside the volume.

The reason for this requirement is, that I have one named volume that is mounted into the home directory of a "user" container (basically a container that belongs to a single user). Now this user can have mutliple applications and I would like to keep a single named volume per user but have them seperated into their own folders inside the user-container home directory.

I don't see why this isn't possible because volume mounts also correspond to a folder somewhere on the harddrive, just that it isn't that easy accessible (or easy to find) like a normal bind mount. Of course I might have gotten that one wrong.

Now my question is if there is some workaround how I could nevertheless mount it into a subdirectory inside the volume? E.g. some linux script I could run on the application container?